Referring to a global variable over local one in Arduino Nano
In C code on Arduino Nano, how can I refer to a global variable with the same name as local one?
Example:
int speed = 0;
void setSpeed(int speed) {
  speed = speed; //  set global variable to local one's value
}


You can't. Rename one of the variables.

Or better yet avoid global (non-static) variables in the first place.

Are you absolutely sure it's C? Normally, Arduino comes with a C++development environment. C and C++ are very different languages.

Rename the parameter.
If you want the parameter to appear to be named speed in a header file, you can still declare the function as void setSpeed(int speed);. Only the definition needs to use a different name.
